# Hide unread indicator for pinned Gmail tabs in Firefox

Tags: gmail, firefox

There's an annoying indicator on my pinned Gmail tabs in Firefox whenever I receive a new mail. I believe this is default FF behavior for whenever the `<title>` of a page changes. I hate this because it causes me to impulsively check my new mails. Anyone know how to get rid of it?

[image: indicator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this discussion](https://support.mozilla.org/eu/questions/1270061) will answer your question. In that thread, the relevant CSS for userChrome.css is provided as:

```
.tabbrowser-tab > .tab-stack >
  .tab-content[pinned][titlechanged]:not([selected="true"]){
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

[The following guide](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html) will explain how to set up userChrome.css for your browser profile. Be sure to do the additional step for Firefox 69+.